Getting an U-boot FIT signed image
I'm trying to generate an U-Boot Signed FIT image containing kernel + dtb.
After generating the kernel, the dtb and the keys, I
mkimage -f fitImage_sign.its -K devicetree.dtb -k <path to the folder containing the keys> -r fitImage

EDIT: I noticed that the first time I execute the command above I got
Failed to add verification data for 'signature' signature node in 'conf' configuration node

with fitImage_sign.its as below
/dts-v1/;

/ {
        description = "Kernel fitImage for Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro)/5.15+gitAUTOINC+5aedde3bc3/sama5d27-sd96-secure-boot";
        #address-cells = <1>;

        images {
                kernel {
                        description = "Linux kernel";
                        data = /incbin/("./uImage");
                        type = "kernel";
                        arch = "arm";
                        os = "linux";
                        compression = "none";
                        load = <0x20008000>;
                        entry = <0x20008000>;
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
                fdt {
                        description = "Flattened Device Tree blob";
                        data = /incbin/("./devicetree.dtb");
                        type = "flat_dt";
                        arch = "arm";
                        compression = "none";
                        hash {
                                algo = "sha1";
                        };
                };
    };

        configurations {
                default = "conf";
                conf {
                        kernel = "kernel";
                        fdt = "fdt";
                        signature {
                                algo = "sha1,rsa2048";
                                key-name-hint = "samkey";
                                padding = "pkcs-1.5";
                                sign-images = "kernel", "fdt";
                        };
                };
    };
};

but when I run
fit_check_sign -f fitimage -k devicetree.dtb 

I got
Verifying Hash Integrity for node 'conf'...  error!
No 'signature' subnode found for '(null)' hash node in 'conf-1' config node
Failed to verify required signature 'key-samkey'
Signature check Bad (error 1)

